# WOFF font not supported in Android (Moto g4, nougat)

Tags: android, fonts, webfonts, android-assets, android-7.0-nougat

In application I have placed some fonts into assets folder. I am applying font on runtime to textview. All fonts types are woff. App is throwing exception of font not found from assets.

Earlier i have tried with otf type font at that time app was running fine.

I am pretty sure something is wrong in Nougat.

Can anyone guide me how to apply WOFF font type in all android OS?

Even i have tested app with WOFF font in 5.0 and 6.0. Its running good.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This would include linking to a font that is failing, plus showing your code that applies the font and the full Java stack trace generated by that code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android RunTime exception "Font asset not found" for .woff font files in android nougat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342572/android-runtime-exception-font-asset-not-found-for-woff-font-files-in-android)