# Android RunTime exception "Font asset not found" for .woff font files in android nougat

Tags: android-7.0-nougat, woff

I am developing one application, where  I need to use .woff fonts. I have written the following code to get font type face from .woff file and set into textview.

```
     hellofont = getFont("fonts/AvenirLTStd-Black.woff");
    //welcomefont = getFont ( "fonts/AvenirLTStd-Heavy.woff");

    thankufont = getFont("fonts/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf");

    TextView text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1id);
    text1.setTypeface(hellofont);

    TextView text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text2id);
    text2.setTypeface(thankufont);



public Typeface getFont( String fontName){
    try {
        Typeface content = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getAssets(), fontName);
        return content;
    }

    catch(RuntimeException e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    return  null;

}
```

This code works fine on android 5.0 and 6.0 devices. But it is giving exception ( Font asset not found fonts/AvenirLTStd-Black.woff )on android 7.0 devices. 
I have tested ttf and otf fonts on android 7.0 devices and it is working fine. Only woff fonts gives this exception.

I have attached the screen shot also which shows the fonts in assests/fonts folder. [asset folder with woff fonts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i88vq.png)

Can anyone help me" what is the issue here?

Thanks in advance
Krishna

Answer (score 2):

WOFF support in Android 7.0 and 7.1 appears to be at least partially broken, with such fonts being unloadable from package `assets` directories. Your best option, if you are supporting Nougat, is to get TTF or OTF versions of your fonts and use those instead.

Comment: Hi Chris, do you know of any bugs on google that is already tracking this? I'm noticing this as well.

Comment: @clu unfortunately no. I only found out about this by searching for answers myself. I wish I had added the source I found to the answer, because I can't find it in my browser history anymore. :(